# Frame Callbcak for AxWindowsMediaPlayer

Tags: c#, windows-media-player, wmp

how can I set a callback for AxWindowsMediaPlayer in order to process videos frame-by-frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible.

Comment: Is it possible to "pause" the video at reaching the last frame? How?